# Modify RequestUri in C# WebApi

Tags: asp.net, encryption, webapi, sendasync, delegatinghandler

I have a ASp.Net WebApi and I add the DelegatingHandler for modify the requestUri.

I tried some examples without results, It is possible?

I Would like to encrypt (client) Decrypt (WebApi) part of the URL.

In the WebApi exists the controller with the route:

api/employee/getInfo/{name}/{lastname}/{date}

From my web client I do the GET to the URL:
http://localhost/api/employee/getInfo/jhon/smith/010525

In the client interceptor I'm encrypt the last part of the URL, (base64 for the example)
http://localhost/api/employee/getInfo/amhvbi9zbWl0aC8wMTA1MjU=

Then in the SendAsync from DelegatingHandler that I want is decrypt the last part to
restore to the original URL to the webapi executes the proper webapi function.

thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I did the next:

I added an additional route to my controller
[Route("api/employee/getInfo/{payload}")]
in the webapi

in the client interceptor change the original call
http://localhost/api/employee/getInfo/jhon/smith/010525
to
http://localhost/api/employee/getInfo/EncryptedInfo

finally in the DelegatingHandler

decrypt and convert to QueryString
http://localhost/api/employee/getInfo?name=jhon&lastname=smith&date=010525

I don't know if it's the correct way but for the moment is working.
If somebody have a better and correct solution please share.

thanks.